# StatusCode: 404, Response when calling the Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I have a Web API which uploads the File content to the server.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SaveFileContent")]
public async Task<FileResponse> SaveFileContent([FromForm] SaveFileContentRequest request)
{
     return await _service.SaveFile(request);
}
```

This is my call to the API:

```
public async Task<FileResponse> SaveFileContent(SaveFileContentRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var uri = "https://www.mycompanyurl.com";
        
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                 using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(request.File))
                 {
                     fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

                     form.Add(fileContent, "file", request.FileName);
                     form.Add(new StringContent(request.MemberId), "MemberId);
                     form.Add(new StringContent(request.Country), "Country);

                     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Document/SaveFileContent", form);
                     FileResponse result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileResponse>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                     return result;
                 }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

I get this response at  PostAsync():

```
   {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
   {
        Date: Sun, 21 Apr 2013 12:00:03 GMT
        Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
        Content-Length: 165
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   }}
```

When I try to run the API in my local -  and use the localhost uri -
var uri = "http://localhost:51515";

It is working fine and getting the 200 OK response.

Comment: What happens if you use HTTPS locally?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the full route

```
[Route("~/api/Document/SaveFileContent")]
public async Task<FileResponse> SaveFileContent([FromForm] SaveFileContentRequest request)
```